# Standard style for text that opens hover tool tip?

Tags: forms, interaction-design, user-expectation, design-patterns

Is there a standard style for text that opens a tool tip upon hover?
E.g. "Learn more" text where the user hovers over it and it opens a tool tip.

Someone on my team had mentioned displaying the "Learn more" with a dotted line underneath to denote its a hover tool tip, but I haven't seen that styling consistently used on text that opens a tool tip on hover.

Comment: A dotted underline is usually the standard style of the [abbr-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/abbr). When you hover an abbreviation which is marked up with the abbr-element, the provided description appears in a tooltip.

Comment: Be careful: if the information only appears when you hover, then people who don't use a mouse can't see the information (this would include mobile users and people who have a disability that requires them to use only a keyboard, who may or may not use a screenreader). For this reason, I use a button with a popover instead.

Answer (score 4):

Most applications/websites either have an *icon* (often a question mark) to indicate you can hover over it (but then the hover only works on the icon, not the label) or no special formatting at all. The answer [here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/76157/64458) suggests using a dotted line as well; I vaguely remember old Windows (3.x) help files working the same way.

Stack Exchange has a lot of labels / links with tooltips:

- almost all dates/timestamps (the 'asked 14 mins ago', which appears on your user card while I'm writing this, the two 'today's currently under the question title)
- the links under each post ('share', 'edit', 'follow', etc.)
- most cases where a number larger than 1000 isn't shown exactly, such as the number of views of a question

They do not have a common style. Perhaps if they would, users on a touchscreen device would wonder about what the common style would mean; after all, they are unable to access hovers.

Answer (score 3):

The only thing that could be considered a standard really is the question mark in a circle icon, as @Glorfindel mentioned. Apart from that, it's what fits well with the rest of your content and UI design. As long as people can see that something is interactive.

Can I ask you to look into making them accessible?
https://inclusive-components.design/tooltips-toggletips/
https://www.sarasoueidan.com/blog/accessible-tooltips/

Comment: Funnily enough I was just implementing a tooltip component today in a web app, and for the life of me I wasn't able to get half the screen readers I have to recognize it. As far as I can tell, the support for tooltips is pretty patchy.